How to make component which is generated by router outlet to be full width and height. Angular
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
  <app-header></app-header>
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>

I have such default-layout structure. But when i am visiting for example app-home component, it's height and width is 0. Approach with :host probably is not good because i need to apply this to each component which will be created. Parent div (this one div class="flex-grow") has full width and heigth.



If you are targeting browsers that support display:grid, then you can use it to solve your problem.
The following snippet relies on the behaviour of Angular routing to insert the routed component as a sibling of the router-outlet element in the DOM.


.app-content {
  /* 
    The available height will be distributed equally between children of this element.
    Children with display:none won't be considered.
  */
  display: grid;
}

.app-content router-outlet {
  display: none;
}


/* 
  Some styles to actually see the elements in the example.
  Not relevant to the problem at hand
*/

app-header,
app-footer {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: gray;
}

app-some-content {
  display: block;
  background: red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.min-h-screen {
  min-height: 100vh
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<div class="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
  <app-header>Header</app-header>
  <div class="flex-grow app-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <!-- Angular inserts the routed component right after the router-outlet  element -->
    <app-some-content>Content</app-some-content>
  </div>
  <app-footer>Footer</app-footer>
</div>




Very interesting solution, tested and it works, thanks! But I have a question, as i am using tailwind I will have such code . So the question, is it ok to apply styles to router-outlet?

Angular seems to preserve any classes that you specify on the router-outlet,
so the approach that you propose should also work.
